# search query via http using JSON

Tags: php, json, api

I am sending an API request and want to submit a search term inside the URL:

```
$query="My Query";
$query_encode= urlencode($query);

$url_json="API_URL".$query_encode
$json = file_get_contents($url_json);
```

What I want to do is that "My Query" should contain a more complex term like:

```
"word1 word2" (word3 OR word4) AND word5
```

My problem is that I want to get the results from the API (database) that match excactly "word1 word2" so I need to somehow send the quoatation marks via http.

Does someone has an idea how I need to set up the content of My Query including the required quotation marks to send a query with the phrase, not just the words

```
$query="My Query";
```

Comment: not sure what you mean, can you explain more?

Comment: it's like when you use google. when you search for 

word1 word2 

you get results where a text contains word1 word2

But I am searching for parts in the text that contain 
"word1 word2" 
(this phrase). thus i need to send somehow the quotation marks via http, but first I need to define my variable $query. How should i declare that variable $query

Comment: what is the issue? can u what your code produces? urlencode should replace the spaces with '+' sign, i think this is what you want so what is the issue?

Comment: the problem are the quotation marks (I just edited the question) because i need to query the phrase, not just the words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to send the quotes then include it in your query.

you set a string value inside quotes in PHP. so what you have right now are not additional quotes that you want to send along in the request but the quotes that will be parsed and removed by PHP.

you should do something like:

```
$query='"My Query"';
```

this will result in something like `%22My+Query%22`

urldecode this later to get back `"My Query"` as string value.

Answer (score 0):

Put the quotes in the string. `urlencode()` will take care of encoding them properly. Also, you need `?` between the URL and the query parameters, and you probably need to supply a name for the parameter (I'm assuming it's named `query` in the code below, you need to get the actual parameter from the API specification).

```
$query = '"word1 word2"';
$query_encode = urlencode($query);
$url_json = "API_URL?query=$query_encode";
$json = file_get_contents($url_json);
```